# How can I search for a code snippet in all folders/files of a site?

Tags: search, drupal, coda

How can I search for a code snippet in all folders/files of a site?

I can't find the line of code I'm looking for. It's a large site and looking through file by file is not reasonable. How can I go about finding this snippet?

Other details: 
It's a Drupal site
I use a Mac
Code editing software I currently have avail: Coda, Text Wrangler, Dreamweaver

Any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `grep` - take a closer look at this tool here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-finding-files-by-content/

FYI: it is a command-line tool.

Also consider that Drupal may be storing something within the database, even the PHP code (which happens when you have PHP filter enabled for some contents and put PHP inline). Thus you may not find the specific code snippet within the code of the application and then you will probably need to look into the database.

Comment: I've given this a try (grep "string"*.php) but the command line seems to never stop working (meaning nothing happens) and gives me no response. This a server issue do you think?

Comment: No, there is a lot of files to walk and find the correct one. Exercise on smaller amount of files first to find the correct command you need. The thing is the files were not indexed by grep before, thus they need to be walked during processing of your expression. It sometimes takes a lot of time, but if the command is correct, the results will be correct also. Also you can try `man grep` from command line.

Comment: Woo hoo, I found the snippet! Thanks for walking me through it, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

While grep via a terminal will work wonderfully for OSX and *nix users, those on Windows may find that grep isn't available.

For Windows users who want a solution to this, you can try the following:

1) Using cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com), which can be installed with grep

or

2) Grabbing a copy of grepWin ([http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html](http://www.cygwin.com)); a grep tool with a frontend UI.